# Gradle + Kotlin + Kotlin-Kover show wrong coverage for multi-module project

Tags: java, kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am working on the Intellij IDEA plugin. I have the following setup for project:

- Gradle: 7.3.3
- Kotlin: 1.6.10
- Java: 11

I faced a case when the **Kotlinx-Kover** (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover) report doesn't have coverage for some files/classes. However, I have a test where functions from files/classes are used. I run a test with debug and functions were called.
[Click here to see report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKPF6.png)

By the way, I have a test in module A for class in module A, but the class function from module A calls a function from module B. As a result, the function from module B doesn't have coverage.

Below you can see an example of my build.gradle.kts.

```
plugins {
  id("java")
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.6.10"
  id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.3.1"
  id("org.jetbrains.changelog") version "1.3.1"
  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.19.0"
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.5.0"
}

tasks.koverMergedHtmlReport {
   isEnabled = true                       
   htmlReportDir.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("my-merged-report/html-result"))
   excludes = listOf("generated.psi.impl.*")
}
    
kover {
   isDisabled = false                      
   coverageEngine.set(kotlinx.kover.api.CoverageEngine.INTELLIJ) 
   intellijEngineVersion.set("1.0.656")
   jacocoEngineVersion.set("0.8.7")       
   runAllTestsForProjectTask = true             
}
```

I tried also the Jacoco plugin (0.8.7) for reporting, however, it showed less coverage than Kotlinx-Kover. I think because Kover takes into account Kotlin's features. Previously, this project works on lower versions of Kotlin, Gradle, Java, and Jacoco shows coverage ~ 78%. Now Jacoco shows 45%, Kover - 53%, but the amount of code has not changed.

I think there is some misconfiguration or I missed smth in the Gradle multi-module project configuration.

**I don't know why functions don't have coverage if they are called in tests.** Please tell me what could be causing this problem.

Comment: any update about this ?

Comment: @YounesBenTlili actually not. Currently in Ukraine I don’t have time to fix this issue. Will update if I find root cause.

Comment: I tried to downgrade versions: Kotlin 1.6.10 -> 1.5.32, Gradle 7.3 -> 6.9.2. As a result, my project coverage was increased to 66%. However, I know that it should be around 80% (+-5%) on old versions of Kotlin and Gradle and with Java 1.8. It seems that the agent in runtime does not use the classes that I have in the classpath. It is strange because there are similar tests in the same module and they have some coverage. I saw some exceptions during test running, but tests are PASSED.
Exception during the test stops working of coverage agent, that's why coverage is not collected for classes.